# Maxima (software) - derivatives as functions

Tags: maxima

Problem: I have a function - let´s say

f(x,y):=x^2*y^3,

with Jacobian and Hessematrix;

Now I want to evaluate these objects at a certain point and then use the results for further calculations, e.g. the Hessian in (2,3).

hm(x,y):=hessian(f(x,y),[x,y]); gives the matrix as a function in x and y, - however,

mymatrix:=ev(hm(x,y),x=2,y=3);

leads to error:

define: argument cannot be an atom or a subscripted memoizing function; found: mymatrix
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);

hessian(f(x,y),[x,y]);
ev(%,x=2,y=3);

gives me the Hessian at the point - 
however,

mymatrix:=%

leads to the same error as above.

(In fact I don´t need the matrix itself but the inverse & the Jacobian as well for gradient descents - but I think, once I´ve one of them I´ll manage the rest too ...)

Apologies if the question has already been posed - I did not succeed to find anything helpful - will be grateful for every response!

Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` is for defining functions. `:` is for assigning to a variable. I think you want `mymatrix : <some expression>;`